# Approximation of objective based on statistical distance

Tags: distance-functions, kullback-leibler

I am a computer science researcher (mostly theoretical) currently in midst of statistics and not able to figure out how to proceed.

At an abstract level, I have a hypothesis for an unknown distribution and I use this hypothesis in my calculations. However, I want to be able to say something about the optimality of this solution based on the statistical distance(any measure) between my hypothesis and the unknown distribution.

To put it more concretely, consider this example:

Suppose we have a uniform distribution on support $[0,V]$. Let $X_i = 1$ if $v_i \geq \frac{V}{2}$ and $X_i = -1$ otherwise. Clearly, in this case $Pr( X_i = 1) = Pr(X_i = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Suppose I make n draws from this distribution and $X = \sum X_i$.

Chernoff bounds allow us to prove that $Pr(X > a) \leq e^{\frac{a^2}{2n}}$. This is great but if instead of uniform distribution(my hypothesis) I have some other distribution with statistical distance (from the hypothesis) bounded by a constant could I make a similar statement accounting for this error (in terms of statistical distance)?

I do not expect a specific answer for this question but a general direction to proceed for tackling these kind of problems. I just have this feeling that someone must have thought of such things in statistics and there may be wealth of knowledge around these questions that I am just not aware of. For example, I looked at a few statistical distance measures (like the Kullback-Leibler distance) but they don't seem to be helpful in this case... at least not to me.

I would really appreciate any help in this.